# Workflow Service Certificates expired in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow-manager, certificate

We have SharePoint 2013 Workflow Service certificates listed below and they all are expired now. What is the best way to renew these certificates?

1. AppServerGeneratedSBCA – Root Certificate for Service Bus
2. FQDN.com – Service Bus Farm and Encryption Certificate
3. FQDN.com – Workflow Manager Services and Encryption Certificate
4. WorkflowOutbound – Workflow Manager Outbound Signing Certificate

Change certificates with Domain CA issued certificates using "Set-SBCertificate", "Set-WFCertificate" and "Set-WFNextOutboundCertificateReference" Workflow Power Shell commands, is it the right model?

Is it possible to simply replace them using self-signed certificates created from IIS? If yes, what are the steps?

Or is there a direct way to renew the above already expired certificates?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you resolved the problem, I have the same one

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you at least install [CU4](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/4019220/description-of-the-cumulative-update-4-for-workflow-manager-1-0) for workflow manager 1.0. Because renewing the expired farm certificates was not allowed before this update.

To change Workflow Manager Farm Certificates, you could refer to this article:https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/whereismysolution/2017/02/08/changing-my-workflow-manager-farm-certificates/

Comment: Thanks for your response. As per the reference article, we need to use four different Thumbprints. How should we create them? If I create self-signed certificates from IIS, will that work or do we need to follow different steps? Please let me know.

Comment: Check this:http://www.harbar.net/articles/wfm3.aspx

Comment: harbar.net link did not help. I have installed the latest CU (CU5) for workflow manager 1.0 in my SP server now but still can't renew already expired certificate.

As soon as I run Stop-SBFarm or Get-SBFarm commands, I always get the below error.
"Thumbprint not found in the certificate store LocalMachine\My"

Thumbprint in the above error is my expired certificate's thimbprint. I have verified and the expired certificate is still present in my server (mmc).

Please let me know if there is any other config that I need to do before Stop-SBFarm command.